# PHP checking mysql connection

Tags: php, mysql

I am building a project with installation (suck as WordPress) and the user provides database information (server, username, password and database). Now, I have to check if it can connect to the provided database. I tried this code, but it seems that it does not work (I am using Mysqli btw):

```
public function checkDataBaseConnection($server, $user, $pass, $db)
{
    $conn = @mysqli_connect($server, $user, $pass, $db);
    if(mysqli_connect_error())
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        mysqli_close($conn);
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

What other way can I use to check if the server can connect to the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing: Remove the `@`, that suppresses some php warnings.

Second thing: Try this:

```
public function checkDataBaseConnection($server, $user, $pass, $db)
{
    $conn = @mysqli_connect($server, $user, $pass, $db);
    if(!$conn)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        //mysqli_close($conn); why would you close the connection?
        return $conn;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

```
if (checkDataBaseConnection($server, $user, $pass, $db))
   echo "Success!";
else
   echo "Fail.";
```

By the way you just can do this way

```
mysqli_connect($server, $user, $pass) or die('Connection failed');
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you look at the PHP page for [mysqli_connect](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.connect.php) you can see this example:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');

/*
 * This is the "official" OO way to do it,
 * BUT $connect_error was broken until PHP 5.2.9 and 5.3.0.
 */
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') '
            . $mysqli->connect_error);
}

/*
 * Use this instead of $connect_error if you need to ensure
 * compatibility with PHP versions prior to 5.2.9 and 5.3.0.
 */
if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
    die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
            . mysqli_connect_error());
}

echo 'Success... ' . $mysqli->host_info . "\n";

$mysqli->close();
?>
```